# How to update ReadTheDocs Project Name and URL

Tags: read-the-docs

I'm working on a Python package where we decided to update the package's name after an initial release of the package and documentation under the old name.

Logging into the associated ReadTheDocs (RTD) account, I'm able to navigate to the projectand change the name from oldproject to newproject. That changed the display name in the "Project Dashboard" in the RTD account but doesn't affect the associated URL for the RTD build.

The project's RTD URL was initially `oldproject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html`. I'm hoping we can update it to be `newproject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html`. Can anyone point me in the right direction to update the URL, but retain our prior documentation build history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended that you create a new project. You can delete the old project or perhaps create a text explaining that it's been renamed.

See: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-change-my-project-slug-the-url-your-docs-are-served-at

Comment: Thanks for the help. We just released a version 0.1 and almost immediately realized we wanted to change the name. So there should be less harm in deleting the old project and moving to a new one than there would be with a more established project.